# When does Google Nearline delete files via lifecycle management?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

**TL;DR** I want to know if the lifecycle rules I created for Google nearline are correct, but Google Cloud Storage has not deleted the files I think it should in my test, despite waiting a couple of days.

**The Longer Version**

I'm setting up Google Nearline storage for backups using versioning & I'm trying to manage the saving of old versions. I've read through [the documentation on Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) and I think I understand, but it's not behaving as I expect.

Here's the situation.

Following the examples in the documentation, I set up the lifecycle management to keep 6 versions of files, deleting any that are older than that. Here's the `json` document I used to set that up:

```
{
    "rule": [
        {
            "action": {
                "type": "Delete"
            },
            "condition": {
                "numNewerVersions": 6
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I implemented that rule (saved in a file called `nearline.json`) with

```
gsutil lifecycle set nearline.json gs://bucket_name
```

I checked to ensure that the rule was successfully applied with

```
gsutil lifecycle get gs://bucket_name
```

and got back `{"rule": [{"action": {"type": "Delete"}, "condition": {"numNewerVersions": 6}}]}` as a reply - so, it appears the rule was successfully applied.

Next, I set out to test it, by executing the following commands to create a simple test file with multiple revisions:

```
# append the current unix timestamp to my test file
echo "Date = $(date +%s)" >> test.txt

# send the new revision to nearline
gsutil cp test.txt gs://bucket_name
```

I did this a total of 10 times.

Next, I checked to see what Google shows in the bucket. Running gsutil ls -la gs://bucket_name gives:

```
 23  2016-10-08T15:59:59Z  gs://bucket_name/test.txt#1475942400031000  metageneration=1
 46  2016-10-08T16:00:09Z  gs://bucket_name/test.txt#1475942410008000  metageneration=1
 69  2016-10-08T16:00:18Z  gs://bucket_name/test.txt#1475942418466000  metageneration=1
 92  2016-10-08T16:00:26Z  gs://bucket_name/test.txt#1475942426563000  metageneration=1
115  2016-10-08T16:00:38Z  gs://bucket_name/test.txt#1475942438484000  metageneration=1
138  2016-10-08T16:00:44Z  gs://bucket_name/test.txt#1475942444562000  metageneration=1
161  2016-10-08T16:00:54Z  gs://bucket_name/test.txt#1475942454455000  metageneration=1
184  2016-10-08T16:01:06Z  gs://bucket_name/test.txt#1475942466301000  metageneration=1
207  2016-10-08T16:01:16Z  gs://bucket_name/test.txt#1475942476052000  metageneration=1
230  2016-10-08T16:01:50Z  gs://bucket_name/test.txt#1475942510806000  metageneration=1
```

So, again, it looks like everything is successful. Except that, instead of seeing only six entries, I see all ten.

I should see six entries because the rule I set up says to delete items with at six or more newer versions. That should include the first four versions in the list above because they all have six ore more newer versions.

Now the documentation does say "if an object meets the conditions for deletion, the object might not be deleted right away", but it has been a couple of days & it hasn't happened. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32407450/2008384) in which it is stated that "there is no guarantee that it will be deleted immediately, but it will usually happen in less than a day".

So, it appears that one of three things is going on:

1. I just haven't waited long enough
2. There's something wrong with my lifecycle rule
3. There's something wrong with the way I'm testing it

Can anyone tell me which of these three it is?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wait a little longer. 
Since the Cloud Storage Nearline is used for data that you do not aspect to access frequently, it probably requires more time in order to apply the livecycle rules than the other Google Cloud Storage options.

"*Data you do not expect to access frequently (i.e., no more than once per month). Typically this is backup data for disaster recovery, or so called "cold" storage that is archived and may or may not be needed at some future time.*"

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes

Comment: Thanks for your reassurance :-) So, just to confirm: the rule I set up looks correct and the test I'm running appears valid?